# Dynamic Dictionary values c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `string` key 'KEY' and different data types values like:

```cs
int id 
String name
Object obj
Long storage
```

How can I store these variables in a Dictionary against a single key?

Comment: Dictionary<string, object>

Comment: If you mean all values together, then you will need to put them into a class.

Comment: In the .Net world, this is an **antipattern**; a sign a BIG mistake was made earlier in the design process. Sometimes you push through anyway, because you're too far along, but it's still a mistake nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
class MyThing
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public object Obj {get;set;}
  public long Storage {get;set;}
}      

Dictionary<string, MyThing> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyThing>
{
   ["key1"] = new MyThing { Id = 1 },
   ["key2"] = new MyThing { Name = "Fred" },
}
```